# Python: Problems writing data to bootstrapTable

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask, datatables

I am trying to pass the data obtained through a select to a table, however I realize that there is a problem with "character encoding", I think.

This example is the data output straight from the function that pulls data from the database:

```
[{'NOME': 'FULANO', 'BAIRRO': u'Bar\xe3o', 'CIDADE': u'Len\xe7a', 'RUA': u'R. Machado', 'SERVICO': u'Instala\xe7\xe3o', 'ID': '83070'},
```

Now I render my template with the datas, simple way:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('index.html',dados=getAllOS())
```

Output using console log:

```
[{&#39;NOME&#39;: &#39;FULANO&#39;, &#39;BAIRRO&#39;: u&#39;Barão&#39;, &#39;CIDADE&#39;: u&#39;Lença&#39;, &#39;RUA&#39;: u&#39;R.Machado&#39;, &#39;SERVICO&#39;: u&#39;Instalação&#39;, &#39;ID&#39;: &#39;83070&#39;},
```

I can't remove this encoding, it prevents me from using bootstrapTable or DataTable to write my table, as it doesn't identify the column names with the objects.

```
    <table id="table1"   data-toggle="true"
      data-toolbar="#toolbar"
      data-search="true"
      data-show-columns="true"
      data-pagination="true"
      data-height="500">


    </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
      var data = "{{dados}}"
      console.log(data);

      var columns = [{"field": "ID", "sortable": true, "title": "ID"}, {"field": "NOME", "sortable": true, "title": "NOME"},
      {"field": "SERVICO", "sortable": true, "title": "SERVICO"}, {"field": "CIDADE", "sortable": true, "title": "CIDADE"},
      {"field": "BAIRRO", "sortable": true, "title": "BAIRRO"},
      {"field": "RUA", "sortable": true, "title": "RUA"}];

      $('#table1').bootstrapTable({
        data: data,
        columns: columns
      });
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: You haven't shown your template

Comment: Also, are you using Python 2? You should be using Python 3 now, Python 2 is obsolete and no longer supported

Comment: Updated, yeah, I'm using python 2, but I have an app  py2 working

Comment: `var data = "{{ dados | safe }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **|safe** to disable automatic escaping.

```
var data = "{{ dados|safe }}"
```

Alternatively, you could use a [jinja for loop](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) to add rows to the table and not have to use any jquery